# Imagemap that displays information

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I want to create an Imagemap that allows me to click on a certain area and then get a stored value from that click.

I have a map of NZ with corresponding values associated with each location. I want the user to click on a location (maybe highlighted with pins) and then get a value from that which will be used in another calculation.

I'm doing this on HTML as it is going on a website.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: How have you stored the values associated with each location?

Comment: I haven't stored the values yet. That is just what I am planning on doing at this stage. I'm fairly new to HTML and programming.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following links. Hope it helps.

http://www.landofcode.com/html-tutorials/html-image-maps.php

http://www.tomakewebsite.com/html/image-maps.html

try giving different IDs to different images, i.e. store those values in ID format and then fetch those IDs by document.getElementById(), write that code to fetch value(id) on the onClick() event.